# How to retain text change on Javascript after reloading browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window-resize

I'm very new to Javascript. I've created my first code from scratch and what I've done is that the longer wording on the tabs are replaced by the shorter wording when the screen width reaches 900px.

These are the titles from the tabs:
**Credit Expert vs Credit Score** into **Credit Expert vs Score**
**How we help people** into **How we help**

It does work when I resize the browser, however, it reverts back to its longer wording when I refresh it. Is there a way to retain it even after refreshing it?

Also, keep in mind **I cannot use CSS or media queries** because the jQuery tabs made it impossible to remove the longer wording when it detects a width less than 900px.

This is the webpage: 
**http://planet.nu/dev/test/index.html**

This is my Javascript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 900) {
        $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Score');
        $('li.hwh').text('How we help');
    } else {
        $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Credit Score');
        $('li.hwh').text('How we help people');
    }
}
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: Look into the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) to call your function on page load.

```
$(window).resize(checkWidth).triggerHandler('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `checkWidth()` when the page is first loaded so the logic gets applied before the page has been resized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkWidth() {
        if ($(window).width() < 900) {
            $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Score');
            $('li.hwh').text('How we help');
        } else {
            $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Credit Score');
            $('li.hwh').text('How we help people');
        }
    }
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
    checkWidth();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Run checkWidth once on page load, so:

```
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
checkWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call checkWidth(); function like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() < 900) {
        $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Score');
        $('li.hwh').text('How we help');
    } else {
        $('li.cvc').text('Credit Expert vs Credit Score');
        $('li.hwh').text('How we help people');
    }
}
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
checkWidth();
});
```